# Update to previous validation script (SCHOOL PROJECT)

Tags: javascript

Well, I have a slight problem in that I read part of the assignment wrong and actually need to have this login any valid email address format and forward it to the 2nd url (myaccount.html). I've tried several things, and while I can get it to login to both the ADMIN page & the MYACCOUNT page, if I put an invalid email in it still logs in (i.e. jdelor1965@yahoo.m). Any ideas?? Thanks...

```
// Chapters 3 & 4 - login.js (updated during week 3)

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function validates the form data and returns a pop-up if conditions are not met.
function validateForm() {
'use strict';

// Get references to the form elements:
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var pattern = '/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/';

// Validate!
if (email == 'admin@titanmusicstore.com' && password == 'LogMeIn') 
{
    window.location = "admin.html";
} 

else if (pattern == '/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/' && pattern == '/^\w+@[a-              zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/') 
{
    window.location = "myaccount.html";
} 

else 
{
    alert('Invalid or incorrect Email or Password!');
}
return false;

}
// End of validateForm() function.
```

---

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FL2c4/

** I'm wondering if the problem is a conflict between the JavaScript being used and the "form action" in the HTML - either email/passowrd combo will bring me to the page listed in the "form action" field, but when I remove that information the login goes nowhere??

To clarify, this is a ***school project*** and not for use in the "real world"! Have received some really good help on here already, so thanks again to those who have assisted. This week, part of our assignment is to change our login validation script to direct the two (2) UID's to different locations. I've read all chapters, watched the videos, and have endlessly researched online but can't figure out how to get this to work - this is what I have, any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated (I can also provide HTML as well - we have a couple pages for that, i.e. index, login, admin, & myaccount).

**JavaScript:**

```
// Script Week 2 - login.js

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function validates the form data and returns a pop-up if conditions are not met.
function validateForm() {
'use strict';

// Get references to the form elements:
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var url = window.location.toLowerCase('login.html');

// Validate!
if (email == 'admin@titanmusicstore.com' && password == 'LogMeIn')
{
window.location = "admin.html";
}

else if (email == 'jdelor1965@yahoo.com' && password == 'LogMeIn') 
{
window.location = "myaccount.html";
return true;
}

else 
{
    alert('Please fill out form accurately - Incorrect UID or Password!');
    return false;
}

} 
// End of validateForm() function.


// Function called when the window has been loaded.
// Function needs to add an event listener to the form.
function init() {
'use strict';

// Confirm that document.getElementById() can be used:
if (document && document.getElementById) {
    var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
    loginForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
}

} 
// End of init() function.

// Assign an event listener to the window's load event:
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: var url = window.location.toLowerCase('login.html'); is not valid syntax, what is the idea behind it? Did you mean window.location.toLowerCase()+'login.html';

Comment: You need to remove all return statements and have ONE return false in the validate like this http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mt8Vb/ - also you need to change your fiddle to HEAD instead of onload

Comment: @mpligjan, that was it. What I'm doing is this: following what we have available to us through our reading & video tutorials, then adding things as I go along from various internet sources if what I've done initially isn't working. What I had at first is closer to what you provided but with all of the information you deleted from the bottom of the JS File (that was from last weeks assignment, and I didn't think I was supposed to remove it). Thank you for your help; I'm going to study the code & syntax to see where I went wrong, but it does work now! Thank you...

Comment: seems like should have had errors thrown in console...if they don't teach you at school to use a browser console and/or other debugging tools...dig into browser console...will save you much time and grief

Comment: @charliefl: it's rather rare that a school will take their students through an in-depth lesson on actually debugging their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New code

```
// Script Week 2 - login.js

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function validates the form data and returns a pop-up if conditions are not met.
function validateForm() {
    'use strict';

    // Get references to the form elements:
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    //    var url = window.location.toLowerCase('login.html'); DELETE -- does nothing

    // Validate!
    if (email == 'admin@titanmusicstore.com' && password == 'LogMeIn') {
        window.location = "http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/";
    } else if (email == 'jdelor1965@yahoo.com' && password == 'LogMeIn') {
        window.location = "http://disney.com";
    } else {
        alert('Please fill out form accurately - Incorrect UID or Password!');
    }
    return false;

}
// End of validateForm() function.


// Function called when the window has been loaded.
// Function needs to add an event listener to the form.
function init() {
    'use strict';

    // Confirm that document.getElementById() can be used:
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
        loginForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    }

}
// End of init() function.

// Assign an event listener to the window's load event:
window.onload = init;
```

You need to return `false` from the validateForm function false every time to stop the form from submitting on its own. Since it's false under every condition, I moved that statement to the end of the function.

I changed the URLs so they would work in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvYVu/2/)**.

I also changed your fiddle from `onLoad` to `No wrap` so your own `onload` handler would work.

Comment: Thanks @Jeffman. Updated as noted but still not working, though I understand what you were trying to convey about the syntax being broken...

Comment: You need to post a fiddle or something. This may not have solved your whole problem, but it has to be done. So now your code is different. You could keep posting updates here, but that's a bit tedious.

Comment: I had it that way initially, but after doing some searching online  changed it because of an example seen elsewhere. Thanks again, trying that now...

Comment: OK, added to the initial question - some additional background: we land at the homepage (index.html), click the login link (login.html), and then based on the email/password entered would want to go to one of two pages (admin.html or myaccount.html). Hope that helps, and thanks for any additional assistance provided...

Comment: @JohnnyD65 New Code and fiddle

Comment: I got so hung up on the braces I didn't notice the returns at first. lol

Comment: @Jeffman, thank you for your help on this as well - glad to see that it would work by keeping in all of the code that was done last week towards the bottom. Question: do either of you have any suggestions that would help to better understand JS besides the obvious?!? It's a bit confusing to me so far, and I'm really trying like hell...

Comment: @mplungjan - very sorry but I'm unable to vote up either of your answers since I can't seem to build any type of reputation here besides being a newbie idiot! Please forgive me for my ignorance, trying very hard to understand this and truly want to be able too...

Answer (score 0):

1. change your fiddle to HEAD instead of onload
2. You need to remove all return statements and have ONE return false in the validate like this http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mt8Vb/

Like this

```
 window.onload = function () { // when the page has loaded
    // find the form and attach an event handler to the submit
    document.getElementById('loginForm').onsubmit = function () {
      // Get references to the form elements:
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
      // Validate!
      if (email == 'xxx...musicstore.com' && password == 'LogMeIn') {
        window.location = "admin.html";
      } else if (email == 'yyy...yahoo.com' && password == 'LogMeIn') {
        window.location = "myaccount.html";
      } else {
        alert('Please fill out form accurately - Incorrect UID or Password!');
      }
      return false; // you never want to actually submit the form 
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Jeffman - very sorry but I'm unable to vote up either of your answers since I can't seem to build any type of reputation here besides being a newbie idiot! Please forgive me for my ignorance, trying very hard to understand this and truly want to be able too...